# Nested projection with spring aggregation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a projection on a mongo collection by using the Spring data Mongo aggregation libraries.

Assume that I have this collection:

```
{
    "_id": "33",
    "name": "Foo",
    "payments": {
        "years": [{
            "year": 2017,
            "quarters": [{
                "quarter": 3,
                "transactions": [{
                    "amount": 800,
                    "type": "VARIA"
                    "dayOfMonth": 10
                }]
            }]
        }]
}
```

I use this mongo aggregation query:

```
db.customers.aggregate(
 { $match: { "_id": {$in:
 ["33", "80"]
 } }},
 { $project: { "payments":{"years":{"quarters":{"transactions":{"amount":1,"type":1}}}} } },
 { $unwind: "$payments.years" },
 { $unwind: "$payments.years.quarters" },
 { $unwind: "$payments.years.quarters.transactions" },
 { $match: { "payments.years.quarters.transactions.amount": {$ne: "0.00" }} },
 { $group: { "_id": "$_id", "payments": {"$push": "$payments.years.quarters.transactions"} }}
 )
```

But I am trying to implement this in my java application now. I use spring-data-mongo.

I tried to do it this way but then I'm receiving zero results.

```
MatchOperation matchAllKlantenStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("_id").in(ids));

ProjectionOperation projectStage = project()
        .and("payments.years.quarters.transactions")
        .nested(bind("type","payments.years.quarters.transactions.type")
        .and("amount", "payments.years.quarters.transactions.amount")
        .and("dayOfMonth", "payments.years.quarters.transactions.dayOfMonth"));


Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        matchAllKlantenStage,
        projectStage,
        unwind("payments.years.quarters.transactions"),
        match(new Criteria("payments.years.quarters.transactions.amount").ne("0.00")),
        group().push("payments.years.quarters.transactions").as("payments")
);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Kind regards,

Kaj

Comment: This is exactly why you do not nest arrays like this. Everyone does this because they "think" it "categorizes", but as you have discovered it clearly does not and it's makes querying extremely difficult. Simply flattening your array structure here solves a lot of problems. Every single "nesting" level here should in fact be "attributes" on the same data detail.

Comment: @NeilLunn I see what you mean, but I'm not capable of changing this structure since this is provided by a third-party service. The structure above is minimized already and there are a lot more properties within the different levels. That's why I want to use mongo aggregation to reduce it to a smaller representation